# Returning NULL from string with appened chars

Tags: java, string, char, character, arrays

The String dexVersion returns null

I tried many things like taking a string and appending a readData[] char to it and it worked fine and i also tried to see if it was a char vs. Character but the results were inconclusive

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

class main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String version = new String("1.0 (Alpha)");

        main main = new main();
        dataHandling data = new dataHandling();
        boolean doneProcessing = false;
        int x = 0,y = 0;
        String dexVersion = new String("v:");
        String pokemon[][] = new String[700][10];
        System.out.println(":");
        System.out.println("POKeUTILITY:MAIN_THREAD_STARTED_IN_STATIC_METHOD_MAIN");
        System.out.println("POKeUTILITY:STARTING_VERSION=" + version);
        System.out.println("POKeUTILITY:DOWNLOADING_POKeDEX_DATA");
        data.download();
        System.out.println("POKeUTILITY:READING_POKeDEX_DATA");
        char readData[] = data.read();
        System.out.println("POKeUTILITY:PROCESSING_POKeDEX_DATA");
        while (doneProcessing = false) {
            if ((readData[x]) == '{') {
                x++;
                while ((readData[x]) != '}') {
                    dexVersion += readData[x];
                    x++;
                }
            }
//            if ((readData[x]) == '[') {
//                x++;
//                while ((readData[x]) != ']') {
//                    dexVersion += readData[x];
//                    x++;
//                }
//            }
            if ((readData[x]) == '%') doneProcessing = true;
            x++;
        }
        System.out.println(dexVersion + ".");
    }
}
class dataHandling {
    public void download() {
        BufferedInputStream dFile;
        FileOutputStream wFile;
        try {
            dFile = new BufferedInputStream(new URL("http://www.harry.technology/pokedex").openStream());
            wFile = new FileOutputStream("pokedex");
            int x = 0,y = 0;
            while ((x = dFile.read()) != -1) {
                wFile.write(x);
            }
            wFile.close();
            dFile.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("POKeUTILITY:ERROR_" + e);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public char[] read() {
        int x = 0,y = 0;
        char input[] = new char[2000];
        String output = new String("");
        try {
            FileReader file = new FileReader("pokedex");
            while ((x = file.read()) != -1) {
                input[y] = convert(x);
                y++;
            }
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("POKeUTILITY:ERROR_" + e);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return input;
    }
    public char convert(int a) {
        switch (a) {
            ASCII SWITCH STATEMENT (left out because of length)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the file "pokedex":

```
{1.0}
[001,Bulbasaur]
%
```

You can see it on my server by visiting: http://www.harry.technology/pokedex

Comment: There are various pretty significant problems with this code, not least the way that your `read()` method always returns 1000 characters, no matter how long the input is. Additionally, it's not clear what you've tried to diagnose the issue. Have you stepped through it in the debugger?

Comment: Additionally, this line: `while (doneProcessing = false)` means you'll *never* go into the loop, because you're setting `doneProcessing` to `false` and using that as the condition. You meant `while (doneProcessing == false)` or better `while (!doneProcessing)`. So I'd expect the final line of the output to be `v:.`. Additionally, you should learn about closing resources in finally blocks - or using a try-with-resources statement if you're using Java 7 or later, and also not creating new strings all the time - instead of `String x = new String("something");` just use `String x = "something";`

Comment: Thanks, i did go through the whole debugger and tried coping code from one of my working programs.  Just a obvious mistake!